# Angular 2 animate element generated by ngFor

Tags: angular, animation

I am new to animations in Angular 2 so I might be missing something obvious, but how do I animate elements generated by an *ngFor loop? It seems like the animations are tied to a component and have to be defined in the @Component decorator?

Is the only solution to create a inner component and have that being created in the *ngFor and then animate that?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is an example of a fade-in animation for elements generated in a `*ngFor` loop.

my.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: ...,
  templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ...,
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeIn', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: '0' }),
        animate('.5s ease-out', style({ opacity: '1' })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
})
```

my-component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray" @fadeIn>I'm an Item</div>
```

NB: If you want to use an animation with a specific state, you should bind the state like this:

```
[@myAnimation]="'myState'"
```

Comment: This really put me on the right track about understanding "state" and how state is bound to a property using the [@TriggerName] syntax.

Comment: You don't need the square brackets, It will also work with @fadeIn

Comment: @UdiMazor True, animation states are not mandatory, therefore databinding and its `[]` are not needed. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there some caveat to the not using the square brackets?  I tried to implement your exact example above and it will only work for me if I bind the @fadeIn property to a class property.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but if items are added dynamically, it will reanimate the whole list again. How would do to only animate the newly added element ?

Comment: I was doing something wrong an regenerates the whole array each time. The solution works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of both fade-in and fade-out animation based on Ploppys answer.

```js
@Component({
  selector: ...,
  templateUrl: 'my-component.html',
  styleUrls: ...,
  animations: [
        trigger('inOutAnimation', [
            state('in', style({ opacity: 1 })),
            transition(':enter', [style({ opacity: '0' }), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ opacity: '1' }))]),
            transition(':leave', [style({ opacity: '1' }), animate('.5s ease-out', style({ opacity: '0' }))]),
        ]),
    ],
})
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray" [@inOutAnimation]="'in'">
```

Comment: What is the use of putting `state('in', style...)` there? It works without that also.

Comment: That's a good question! I copied most of this :)