# How do I perform infinite animations in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, web-animations, angular-animations

Basically, I want to make use of the web-animations-api polyfill in angular (4 currently) to perform infinite animations on elements.

Let's see a basic non-angular example:

```js
var ball = document.getElementById('ball');

ball.animate([
  { transform: 'scale(0.5)' },
  { transform: 'scale(1)' }
], {
  duration: 1000,
  iterations: Infinity,
  direction: 'alternate',
  easing: 'ease-in-out'
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #E57373;
  background: #F06292;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #F06292;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.2.5/web-animations.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="ball" id="ball"><div>
</div>
```

How do I translate that into Angular?

This is what I've tried so far but only works once:

```
animations: [
  trigger('scale', [
    transition('* <=> *', animate('1s ease-in-out', keyframes([
      style({ transform: 'scale(0.5)' }),
      style({ transform: 'scale(1)' })
    ]))) // How do I specify the iterations, or the direction? 
  ])
]
```

Is there a way to do that with the @angular/animation plugin instead of storing a ElementRef and doing it as the example above? or maybe I misunderstood what this plugin is intended for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42963315/angular-2-animate-element-generated-by-ngfor

Answer (score 21):

I was searching infinite animation for my project. There is no documentation for this in `angular.io`. So i tried this way and cost me many hours to achieve this. Hope it will help others.
First define `animation` in your `class`.

```
animations: [
trigger('move', [
  state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
  state('out', style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'})),
  transition('in => out', animate('5s linear')),
  transition('out => in', animate('5s linear'))
]),
]
```

then insert it in your `html`

```
<div [@move]="state" (@move.done)="onEnd($event)"></div>
```

then set `state = 'in'` and in `ngAfterViewInit()` lifecycle hook, update your `state` property value `'out'` with `setTimeout` function and after end callback function, update your `state` property value into `'in'` and check your `state` property value, if `in` then update into `out` by `setTimeout` function like this

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  state = 'in';
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.state = 'out';
    }, 0);
  }
  onEnd(event) {
    this.state = 'in';
    if (event.toState === 'in') {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.state = 'out';
      }, 0);
    }
  }
}
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: Hey Eliyas, why would you do those timeouts etc? I did infinite animation using this thing: onEnd(event) {
      if (this.currentState==="up") {
        this.currentState="down"
      } else {
        this.currentState="up"
      }
  }

Comment: I mean that based on the actual state the onEnd needs to reverse change the variable and thats it

Answer (score 2):

Infinite animations in Angular can be achieved, not much out there on it, but this is working nicely for me for
onenter and onleave animation.

When 'mouseenter' the animation plays in a loop, it stops on 'mouseleave'.

I am using Angular 6.

Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.9.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3

---

```
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'hot-spot',
  templateUrl: './myComp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myComp.component.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('compState', [
      state('small', style({
        opacity: '0.5',
        transform: 'scale(0.8)'
      })),
      state('large', style({
        opacity: '1',
        transform: 'scale(1.2)'
      })),
      transition('small => large', animate('0.6s 100ms ease-in')),
      transition('large => small', animate('0.7s 100ms ease-out'))
    ]),
  ]
})
export class MyComponent {

  state: string = 'none';
  isEnter: boolean = false;


  onMouseEnter(evt: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('onMouseEnter()');
    this.state = 'small';
    this.isEnter = true;
  }

  onMouseLeave(evt: MouseEvent) {
    console.log('onMouseLeave()');
    this.state = 'large';
    this.isEnter = false;
  }

  onEnd(event) {
    if (this.isEnter) {
      if (event.toState === 'small') {
        this.state = 'large';
      }
      else {
        this.state = 'small';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And the HTML

```
<div
  (mouseenter)="onMouseEnter($event)"
  (mouseleave)="onMouseLeave($event)">

  <div>
    <div
      [@compState]="state"
      (@compState.done)="onEnd($event)">

      <button
        (click)="onSceneClick($event,data.sceneId)"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-link" >
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-up" style="font-size:16pt;color:red">
          <br><span style="font-size:12pt">{{data.text}}</span>
        </i>

      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try **WebComponents** to use **Web Animations API** in a declarative way (Animating any html element by using components):

```html
<!-- Add Web Animations Polyfill :) -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/web-animations/2.3.2/web-animations.min.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@proyecto26/animatable-component@1.0.0/dist/animatable-component/animatable-component.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule="" src="https://unpkg.com/@proyecto26/animatable-component@1.0.0/dist/animatable-component/animatable-component.js"></script>

<animatable-component
  autoplay
  easing="ease-in-out"
  duration="800"
  delay="300"
  animation="zoomIn"
  iterations="Infinity"
  direction="alternate"
  style="display: flex;align-self: center;"
>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
</animatable-component>
```

There are a lot of defined animations, but also you can create custom animations by using keyFrames.

Check here to use it with **Angular**, **React**, **VueJS**, etc: https://github.com/proyecto26/animatable-component#framework-integrations